# JQuery not appending correct value to unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function endGame(num) {
    var total = Object.keys(abvMap).length;

    $("#result").empty();

    if(num == total) {
        // you won
        $("#result").append("<h4>YOU WON!</h4><p>You got all " + total + " states!</p>");
    } else {
        console.log(states);
        // didn't get all 51 states
        $("#result").append("<h4>ALMOST!</h4><p>You got " + num + " out of " + total +" states!</p><h3>Missing states:</h3><ul id=\"missing-states-list\"></ul>");
        for(var key in abvMap) {
            if(($.inArray(key, states)) == -1) {
                console.log(key);
                $.get("https://api.census.gov/data/2013/language?get=EST,LANLABEL,NAME&for=state:" + abvMap[key] + "&LAN=625", function(data) {
                    $("#missing-states-list").append("<li><div class=\"tooltip\">" + key + "<span class=\"tooltiptext\">" + data[1][0] + " spanish speakers</span></div></li>");
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The details of this file is irrelevant. The issue here is in the for-loop, where every `key` in the dictionary `abvMap` is being looped through. `states` is an global array that contains states that have already been found, e.g. `states = ["Maryland", "Texas"]`. `abvMap` is a dictionary that contains all 51 states. I'm checking in each iteration of the for-loop of the `key` state have already been found. If not, I make an API call and append that state (and some data from the API) to the list `#missing-states-list`.

Judging by the `console.log()` outputs. There's absolutely no issue with `states` or `key`, it perfectly loops through every state in the dictionary. Even the API calls are correct. However, what's appended to the `#missing-states-list` is always `Wyoming`, which is the last entry in `abvMap`. I have idea why.

Comment: And this has something to do with [tag:Java] because?

Comment: it's javascript, apologies for the typo

Comment: Maybe he/she considered switching to Java after this debacle

Comment: You need to learn about `function scope` and `block scope` to understand what is going wrong in your code. See my answer and the references Zakas book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cause of the problem: lack of understanding `scope`

Check this example to understand the problem:

### `var` creates `function scope`

```js
var funcs = []

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  funcs.push(function() {
    console.log(i)
  })
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) {
  func()
})
```

While you might expect this `forEach` loop to result in number `0` to `9` being printed, instead you get ten times `10`. The cause of this is the variable `i` being declared using `var` keyword, which creates a `function scope` that leads to each `function` in `funcs` holding a *reference* to **the same** `i` variable. At the time the `forEach` loop is executed, the previous `for`-loop has ended and `i` holds 10 (9++ from the last iteration).

Compare how ES6's `let`, which creates `block scope` instead of `function scope`, behaves in this regard:

### `let` (ES6 or officially *ES2015*) creates `block scope`:

```js
var funcs = []

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  funcs.push(function() {
    console.log(i)
  })
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) {
  func()
})
```

Because `let` creates `block scope`, each iteration of the `for` loop has its "own" variable `i`.

### ES5 solution using an `IIFE` wrapper

If you need an ES5 solution, an IIFE (**i**mmediately **i**nvoked **f**unction **e**xpression) wrapper would be the way to go:

```js
var funcs = []

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  funcs.push((function(value) {
    return function() {
      console.log(value)
    }
  }(i)))
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) {
  func()
})
```

Here, `i` is passed as a parameter to each function which stores its own copy `value`.

### The same is true for `for..in` loops:

```js
var funcs = [],
  obj = {
    first: "first",
    last: "last",
    always: "always"
  }
  
for (var key in obj) {
  funcs.push(function() {
    console.log(key)
  })
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) { // outputs: "always", "always", "always"
  func()
})
```

Again, all functions in `funcs` hold the `reference` to the same `key` because `var key` creates a function scope that lives outside of the `for..in` loop. And again, `let` produces the result you'd probably rather expect:

```js
var funcs = [],
  obj = {
    first: "first",
    last: "last",
    always: "always"
  }
  
for (let key in obj) {
  funcs.push(function() {
    console.log(key)
  })
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) {
  func()
})
```

Also compare the excellent (!) book

> [Nicholas C. Zakas: "Understanding ES6"](https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read/#leanpub-auto-block-binding-in-loops), no starch press, p. 8-9.

from which the examples were taken.

Comment: Thanks @connexo. I knew that `let` had tighter scoping than var but didn't know that it worked this way in a loop. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Feel free to upvote if you feel this is a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `$.get` is asynchronous and by the time it returns, key is always at the end of the abvMap loop.

You will need to create an artificial closure around your `$.get` call so that the `key` value, correct as of the time of calling, is maintained.

```
(function (keysafe) {
    $.get("https://api.census.gov/data/2013/language?get=EST,LANLABEL,NAME&for=state:" + abvMap[keysafe] + "&LAN=625", function(data) {
    $("#missing-states-list").append("<li><div class=\"tooltip\">" + keysafe + "<span class=\"tooltiptext\">" + data[1][0] + " spanish speakers</span></div></li>");
    });
}(key));
```

Comment: can you give an example of that?

Comment: I *think* I can. Added to answer. Obviously I cannot test this in context, and that is off top of head.

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be IIFE and I missed a set of parens! Please check my correction.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes using "var" will only display the last item in the list.  To retain each item/element, you need to use "let" so it can rebind to each iteration (ES6).

How about just switching "var" to "let" in the for loop?

> for(**let** key in abvMap) {
>    ...
>   }