# JS - Clicking buttons changes text of element to undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Clicking the buttons 'hi' and 'helo' must change the content of `'.admin-text'` to the respective text according to the plan, but it simply changes it to `'undefined'`.

```js
var admin_text = document.querySelector('.admin-text');

var infra_btns = [document.getElementById('hi'), document.getElementById('helo')];


var infra_html = ["<p>hi</p>", "<p>helo</p>"];

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  infra_btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    admin_text.innerHTML = infra_html[i];
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="admin">
  <div class="admin-nav">
    <button class="adminbtns" id="hi">hi</button>
    <button class="adminbtns" id="helo">helo</button>
  </div>

  <div class="admin-text">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there - you need to use `let` instead of `var` in your `for`-loop, otherwise `i` equals 2 in all your listener functions:

```js
var admin_text = document.querySelector('.admin-text');

var infra_btns = [hi, helo];


var infra_html = ["<p>hi</p>", "<p>helo</p>"];

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  infra_btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    admin_text.innerHTML = infra_html[i];
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="admin">
  <div class="admin-nav">
    <button class="adminbtns" id="hi">hi</button>
    <button class="adminbtns" id="helo">helo</button>
  </div>
  <div class="admin-text"></div>
</div>
```

This happens because variables declared using `var` have *function scope*, and `i` in your listener functions is passed by **reference**, not by *value*, so all your listeners share the same `i`. After the last iteration the last thing the `for`-loop does is `i++`, so `i` equals 2. So your listener tries to access `infra_html[2]` which is `undefined` because your array does not have an element with that index.

This post explains it in detail: [JQuery not appending correct value to unordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957708/jquery-not-appending-correct-value-to-unordered-list/48958037#48958037)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the loop you have

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  infra_btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    admin_text.innerHTML = infra_html[i];
  });
}
```

When the client event handler triggers i will be 3, as the loop has ended previously. You should create a closure.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
   infra_btns[i].addEventListener('click', (function(index) {
      return function () {
         admin_text.innerHTML = infra_html[index];
      }
   })(i));
}
```

or use `let` to create block scoped variable as shown in other answer

Comment: I'd recommend giving the IIFE parameter a different name to make it clear that this is not the outer `i`.