# Javascript. Onclick returns always the same object

Tags: javascript, html

I have got 16 divs of the same class name in html document in the following fashion

```
    <div class="game-selection-tab">
      <h2>30m + 15s</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="game-selection-tab">
      <h2>60m + 0s</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="game-selection-tab">
      <h2>Custom</h2>
    </div>
```

I want to create onclick method that returns h2 text content from particular div. I tried to solve this by using following javascript code.

```
var selectionTabs = document.getElementsByClassName("game-selection-tab");

for(var i = 0; i < selectionTabs.length; i++){

  var tab = selectionTabs[i];
  var content = tab.getElementsByTagName("h2");
  tab.onclick = function(){
   console.log(content[0].textContent);
  }
}
```

The problem is: no matter which div i click, program always returns h2 text content from the last div(in this example "custom").

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery not appending correct value to unordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957708/jquery-not-appending-correct-value-to-unordered-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var selectionTabs = document.getElementsByClassName("game-selection-tab");

for(var i = 0; i < selectionTabs.length; i++){
  (function (index) {
      var tab = selectionTabs[index];
      var content = tab.getElementsByTagName("h2");
      tab.onclick = function(){
       console.log(content[0].textContent);
      }
  })(i);
}
```

The thing is by the time your event attaches to the actual DOM element the for loop execution is complete and the value of i is the max value that it can reach. Hence, isolating the same in a function like this works. The function stores the value of `i` or in this case `index` as the original value that you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
var i = 0
```

by

```
let i = 0
```

and you're done.

A detailed explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957708/jquery-not-appending-correct-value-to-unordered-list/48958037#48958037).

I'll quote my answer for your understanding below.

## Cause of the problem: lack of understanding `scope`

Check this example to understand the problem:

### `var` creates `function scope`

```js
var funcs = []

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  funcs.push(function() {
    console.log(i)
  })
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) {
  func()
})
```

While you might expect this `forEach` loop to result in number `0` to `9` being printed, instead you get ten times `10`. The cause of this is the variable `i` being declared using `var` keyword, which creates a `function scope` that leads to each `function` in `funcs` holding a *reference* to **the same** `i` variable. At the time the `forEach` loop is executed, the previous `for`-loop has ended and `i` holds 10 (9++ from the last iteration).

Compare how ES6's `let`, which creates `block scope` instead of `function scope`, behaves in this regard:

### `let` (ES6 or officially *ES2015*) creates `block scope`:

```js
var funcs = []

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  funcs.push(function() {
    console.log(i)
  })
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) {
  func()
})
```

Because `let` creates `block scope`, each iteration of the `for` loop has its "own" variable `i`.

### ES5 solution using an `IIFE` wrapper

If you need an ES5 solution, an IIFE (**i**mmediately **i**nvoked **f**unction **e**xpression) wrapper would be the way to go:

```js
var funcs = []

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  funcs.push((function(value) {
    return function() {
      console.log(value)
    }
  }(i)))
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) {
  func()
})
```

Here, `i` is passed as a parameter to each function which stores its own copy `value`.

### The same is true for `for..in` loops:

```js
var funcs = [],
  obj = {
    first: "first",
    last: "last",
    always: "always"
  }
  
for (var key in obj) {
  funcs.push(function() {
    console.log(key)
  })
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) { // outputs: "always", "always", "always"
  func()
})
```

Again, all functions in `funcs` hold the `reference` to the same `key` because `var key` creates a function scope that lives outside of the `for..in` loop. And again, `let` produces the result you'd probably rather expect:

```js
var funcs = [],
  obj = {
    first: "first",
    last: "last",
    always: "always"
  }
  
for (let key in obj) {
  funcs.push(function() {
    console.log(key)
  })
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) {
  func()
})
```

Also compare the excellent (!) book

> [Nicholas C. Zakas: "Understanding ES6"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957708/jquery-not-appending-correct-value-to-unordered-list/48958037#48958037), no starch press, p. 8-9.

from which the examples were taken.

Comment: That's why I added exhaustive explanation and an alternative ES5 solution with an IIFE.

Answer (score 1):

It's showing always the same value because you are setting content outside of the `onclick` function. After the for loop, `content` points to the last h2.

Move the content definition inside the `onclick` function.

```
  tab.onclick = function(){
    var content = this.getElementsByTagName("h2");
    console.log(content[0].textContent);
  }
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sygn/mqstvxxt/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the solution below.

```
  var selectionTabs = document.getElementsByClassName("game-selection-tab");

     Object.keys(selectionTabs).forEach((data, index) => {
       var context = selectionTabs[data].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].textContent;
       selectionTabs[data].onclick = function () {
         console.log(context)
       }
     })
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at `Object.values` as that would simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solution:

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('game-selection-tab');
var index = 0;

function getText() {
  alert(this.innerText || this.textContent);
}

for (; index < els.length; index++) {
  els[index].onclick = getText;
}
```

```html
<div class="game-selection-tab">
  <h2>30m + 15s</h2>
</div>
<div class="game-selection-tab">
  <h2>60m + 0s</h2>
</div>
<div class="game-selection-tab">
  <h2>Custom</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't wanna change your HTML to include an "onclick" event on each h2, this code might help you:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
    text = target.textContent || text.innerText;
        console.log(text);
}, false);
```

EDIT
If you want to be more specific and get the content from only your h2's, you could use this:

```
h2s = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
for (var i = 0; i < h2s.length; i++) {
  h2s[i].addEventListener('click', redirect, false);
}

function redirect(e) {
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var text = target.textContent || text.innerText;
  console.log(text);
}
```