# why I'm getting array values as "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a rookie in node.js so I apologize if my question is immature .Basically I'm trying to iterate thorough an array of values for performing certain operation but I don't know why I'm getting the values as `undefined`.

Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    console.log(array[i]); //At this point I'm getting values without any problem
    var sQ = {
        _tag: array[i],
        _pid: data.change_caption_post_mail,
        time: data.change_caption_post_time,
    };

    db.collection('tags')
        .find(sQ)
        .count({}, function(error, numOfDocs) {
            if (error) throw err;
            console.log(array[i]);
            //But here I'm getting values as **undefined**
        });
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `i` is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Change `var i=0` to `let i= 0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript. Onclick returns always the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49223885/javascript-onclick-returns-always-the-same-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i
```

by

```
let i = 0; i < array.length; i++
```

and you're done.

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]); //At this point I'm getting values without any problem
    var sQ = {
        _tag: array[i],
        _pid: data.change_caption_post_mail,
        time: data.change_caption_post_time,
    };

    db.collection('tags')
        .find(sQ)
        .count({}, function(error, numOfDocs) {
            if (error) throw err;
            console.log(array[i]);
            // i will be array.length here in all your callbacks
        });
}
```

## Cause of the problem: lack of understanding `scope`

Check this example to understand the problem:

### `var` creates `function scope`

```js
var funcs = []

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  funcs.push(function() {
    console.log(i)
  })
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) {
  func()
})
```

While you might expect this `forEach` loop to result in number `0` to `9` being printed, instead you get ten times `10`. The cause of this is the variable `i` being declared using `var` keyword, which creates a `function scope` that leads to each `function` in `funcs` holding a *reference* to **the same** `i` variable. At the time the `forEach` loop is executed, the previous `for`-loop has ended and `i` holds 10 (9++ from the last iteration).

Compare how ES6's `let`, which creates `block scope` instead of `function scope`, behaves in this regard:

### `let` (ES6 or officially *ES2015*) creates `block scope`:

```js
var funcs = []

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  funcs.push(function() {
    console.log(i)
  })
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) {
  func()
})
```

Because `let` creates `block scope`, each iteration of the `for` loop has its "own" variable `i`.

### ES5 solution using an `IIFE` wrapper

If you need an ES5 solution, an IIFE (**i**mmediately **i**nvoked **f**unction **e**xpression) wrapper would be the way to go:

```js
var funcs = []

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  funcs.push((function(value) {
    return function() {
      console.log(value)
    }
  }(i)))
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) {
  func()
})
```

Here, `i` is passed as a parameter to each function which stores its own copy `value`.

### The same is true for `for..in` loops:

```js
var funcs = [],
  obj = {
    first: "first",
    last: "last",
    always: "always"
  }
  
for (var key in obj) {
  funcs.push(function() {
    console.log(key)
  })
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) { // outputs: "always", "always", "always"
  func()
})
```

Again, all functions in `funcs` hold the `reference` to the same `key` because `var key` creates a function scope that lives outside of the `for..in` loop. And again, `let` produces the result you'd probably rather expect:

```js
var funcs = [],
  obj = {
    first: "first",
    last: "last",
    always: "always"
  }
  
for (let key in obj) {
  funcs.push(function() {
    console.log(key)
  })
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) {
  func()
})
```

Also compare the excellent (!) book

> [Nicholas C. Zakas: "Understanding ES6"](https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read/#leanpub-auto-block-binding-in-loops), no starch press, p. 8-9.

from which the examples were taken.

Comment: Great explanation sir, thanks a lot for your time and answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you copy in a stock answer instead of marking it as duplicate or adding to the duplicate flag already posted.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to decide on my own whether a question should be marked a duplicate. I see many questions remain active because not enough close votes. For the time being, OP has a correct and exhaustive answer right here.

Answer (score 2):

Change `var i = 0` to `let i = 0`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
console.log(array[i]); //At this point I'm getting values without any problem
var sQ = {
    _tag: array[i],
    _pid: data.change_caption_post_mail,
    time: data.change_caption_post_time,
};

db.collection('tags')
    .find(sQ)
    .count({}, function (error, numOfDocs) {
        if (error) throw err;
        console.log(array[i]);
    });
```

}

**N.B.** When the callback function (`function (error, numOfDocs) {...}`) is executing the for loop is finished. if we declare `var i` then `i` is equal to `array.length` when executing callback so, array[array.length] returns undefined. One of the solutions is to use ES6 `let` which will create callback's block scope `i` for each iteration.

Comment: I guess its not about scope..if u observe the variable value be undefined in call back function as it is async .To tackle this either u assign value to global variable or pass it in the callback result.

Comment: This answer lacks an explanantion as of why that solves the problem, and even what the cause of the problem is.

Comment: Added explanation. Thanks @connexo!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your callback function, the reference of **i** remains only one which is already changed by the time callback is called.

you can change your code to

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    (function(){
    var index = i;
    console.log(array[index]); //At this point I'm getting values without any problem
    var sQ = {
        _tag: array[index],
        _pid: data.change_caption_post_mail,
        time: data.change_caption_post_time,
    };

    db.collection('tags')
        .find(sQ)
        .count({}, function(error, numOfDocs) {
            if (error) throw err;
            console.log(array[index]);
            //But here I'm getting values as **undefined**
        });
    })();
}
```

it should work fine with this tweak

Comment: This code has exactly the same problem as OP's code.

Comment: yeah true, the scope still needs to be inside a function as long as it's ES5